# Deposit DAI on test account

Tags: tokens, hardhat, testnets

i'm forking euthereum mainet via hardhat , how to deposit some DAI or USDC on my test account ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

You should deploy your own DAI and USDC! So basically all tokens are smart contracts.

All you need to do is just copy the source code from [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#code) and [deploy it to your local network with hardhat.](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/project-setup)

If you find it less intuitive, you can use an IDE like Remix to connect to your local network too.

Hope that helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The method I usually use consists in impersonating a "whale" account and sending the tokens to me.

1. Start by going over etherscan in the page of the token, go to "Holders" and pick the address of someone who has enough tokens.
2. Use the hardhat impersonate account tool, to be able to use this address ([docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#impersonating-accounts)):

```js
const whaleAccount = await ethers.getImpersonatedSigner("0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
```

3. Send some tokens to me:

```js
const tx = await tokenContract.connect(whaleAccount).transfer(MY_WALLET, TOKEN_AMOUNT);
```